# Wordpress The Events Calendar Plugin - List View Background Colour Issue

Tags: jquery, css, html-helper, wordpress

I'm trying to look for some help, I've got a wordpress website that I'm working on.

I'm using this plugin called The Events Calendar, but and in List View, the background keeps showing in transparency...

Would somebody be able to help me trigger and find where in the code I can change the background color instead of having it in transparency ??

Here is the link: http://bit.ly/1cJlC8e

Thanks!

Shaun

Comment: wordpress.stackexchange.com might be better for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can add this code to #tribe-events-content.tribe-events-list in your stylesheet like so:

```
#tribe-events-content.tribe-events-list {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background: #FFFFFF; /* ADD A BACKGROUND COLOR HERE */
}
```

That will add a background to the Upcoming Events section so that the text is more easily readable.

[Here's a screenshot of the change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3I2P.jpg)